# Getting a return value from id command in bash

Tags: bash, return-value

Trying to test if a user exists with the id command like the following:

```
id -un username
```

or just

```
id -u username
```

This works great, but I need to just evaluate true or false. Can someone help me understand how I just get back a true false from this command whether the user exists or not. Thanks

```
if { true }; then
  blah
else
  blah
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
id -un username >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo "exists" || echo "nope"
```

Or:

```
if id -un username >/dev/null 2>&1; then
   echo "exists"
else
   echo "Doesn't exist"
fi
```